# Remove Items from Pivot Table Filter Using VBA

Tags: excel, filtering, pivot-table, vba

I am attempting to remove values greater than or equal to 9000 in a pivot table. I am using VBA code and I am able to remove the values from the UOM filter, but I also need to remove values from the OpAc filter that are 9000 or greater.

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Pivot ZP2P").PivotFields("UOM").CurrentPage = "(All)"
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Pivot ZP2P").PivotFields("UOM")
    .PivotItems("""").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("""2").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("EA").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("FOZ").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("ML").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("TU").Visible = False
End With
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Pivot ZP2P").PivotFields("UOM"). _
    EnableMultiplePageItems = True
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Pivot ZP2P").PivotFields("OpAc")
    .Orientation = xlPageField
    .Position = 1
    .PivotItems("9" & "*").Visible = False
End With
```

As you can see, I have attempted to remove items using the wildcard 9* with concatenating the 9 and * as strings.
I am not sure if I have gone about this correctly to remove values >= 9000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been solved. To remove items in the 9000 use the code:

```
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Pivot ZP2P").PivotFields("OpAc")
    .Orientation = xlPageField
    .Position = 1
End With
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Pivot ZP2P").PivotFields("OpAc").CurrentPage = "(All)"
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Pivot ZP2P").PivotFields("OpAc")
        For o = 1 To .PivotItems.Count
        With .PivotItems(o)
            If .Name Like ("9*") Then
                .Visible = False
            Else
                .Visible = True
            End If
        End With
    Next o
End With
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Pivot ZP2P").PivotFields("OpAc"). _
    EnableMultiplePageItems = True
```